'GenerateMetaData' is not a valid page export feild
My project runs fine on my local host, but when I try to deploy it to vercel, I get the error
Type error: Page "app/[searchTerm]/page.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.
"generateMetaData" is not a valid Page export field.
I am unsure how to fix this, as I am quite new to typescript, I am unsure what I should change about my page below in order to get it to deploy successfully to vercel.
here is my code
app/[searchTerm]/page.tsx
import getWikiResults from "@/lib/getWikiResults";
import Item from "../components/Item";
type Props = {
  params: {
    searchTerm: string;
  };
};

//metadata
export async function generateMetaData({ params: { searchTerm } }: Props) {
  const wikiData: Promise<SearchResult> = getWikiResults(searchTerm);
  const data = await wikiData;
  //browsers use %20 as spaces, get rid of these and replaace them with normal spaces
  const displayTerm = searchTerm.replaceAll("%20", "");

  // if no result
  if (!data?.query?.pages) {
    return {
      title: `${displayTerm} Not Found`,
    };
  }
  return {
    title: displayTerm,
    description: `Search results for ${displayTerm}`,
  };
}

export default async function SearchResults({ params: { searchTerm } }: Props) {
  const wikiData: Promise<SearchResult> = getWikiResults(searchTerm);
  const data = await wikiData;
  //could be undefined
  const results: Result[] | undefined = data?.query?.pages;
  const content = (
    <main className="bg-slate-200 mx-auto max-w-lg py-1 min-h-screen ">
      {results ? (
        Object.values(results).map((result) => {
          return <Item key={result.pageid} result={result} />;
        })
      ) : (
        <h2 className="p-2 text-xl">{`${searchTerm} Not Found!`}</h2>
      )}
    </main>
  );
  return content;
}




It should be generateMetadata. d not D
